# Unable to access Oracle Linux in VirtualBox : Status is INACCESSIBLE

Tags: virtualbox

I see the below error for a OEL instance I created in Oracle VirtualBox:

```
Cannot attach medium 'D:\oracle_practice\rac\srv1\Oracle-Linux-6.7-disk001.vdi' {954fedb4-2805-4782-8bb8-b8b42aa71e18}: medium is already associated with the current state of machine uuid {3240e3c5-6f8c-4b55-a02d-311195348e28}!.
```

The VM instance on the left pane shows "INACCESSIBLE" and upon right clicking, I See Refresh/Export to OCI/Search options only.

The srv1.vbox file can be found [here](https://cloudsoups.blogspot.com/2021/08/srv1vbox.html).

I was able to access the instance a day ago. After rebooting my host machine, I am seeing this error.

Comment: Does `D:\oracle_practice\rac\srv1\Oracle-Linux-6.7-disk001.vdi` exist?

Comment: Hey Ramhound.. Yes it exists.